# How to get the value for the search function in Node Js?

Tags: html, node.js, express, web, handlebars.js

I have this function to create a search bar using the Express Framework in Node.JS, Handlebars and MySQL. The connection to  MySQL is already functional, body parser already installed, and i already checked the query hardcoded straight inside phpmyadmin (without the req.body) and it worked, but it doesn't work when i applied it to Node.JS

inside the *handlebars* :

```
<form role="form" action="naskah_form/search" method="get">
        <input type='text' name='titlesearch' id='q' placeholder='Enter a keyword...' required autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='submit' value='Search' id='submit'>
</form>
```

inside *naskah_form.js* :

```
router.get('/search', (req,res)=>{
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_test where title LIKE '% "+ 
         req.body.titlesearch + "%'"
    conn.query(sql, (err,results)=>{
    if (err) throw err
        res.json(results[0])
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

I expect the result would be to at least show a list of json of the searched word let's say 'q'. The url is http://localhost:3000/naskah_form/search?titlesearch=q but inside it is blank.
Can anyone guide me on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using the GET method to submit the form then use `req.query.titlesearch` :

```
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query);
})
```

if you are using the POST method to submit the form then `req.body.titlesearch`

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i just changed it into query and it still won't show up

Comment: will you please tell me what response you are getting in `req.body` or `req.query`?

Comment: Let's say i type the word 'q' , the result on the page is still white blank on both of the method but the url is http://localhost:3000/naskah_form/search?titlesearch=q

Comment: try to debug your code try: `console.log("SQL query = ", sql);` and check in the console and manually try that query.

Comment: I have finally solved the issue and use `let sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_test where title LIKE '%"+req.query.titlesearch+"%'"` this instead. I thank you very much for the help ! :D